# Why 'Modified -- ago' link in home page of SE (ProWebmasters) not navigating to the exact place of the comment?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, navigation

When I clicked **"Modified -- ago"** of one of the post in [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), it's navigating the question and not to the exact comment of an answer. But the question URL is passing the ID of that comment. Instead of placing the position in question, we should navigate exactly to the comment which will be more useful for users. Because If we have more answers or comments for a particular question, it will be difficult to find where the exact modification has been done.

Screenshot:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Comments don't bump posts. Only actual modifications to posts (or pokes by the Community user) cause 'modified' to be shown on the homepage.

In this case, the user posted an NAA as an answer, which a moderator converted to a comment. Their username is shown as the modification because they did cause the modification by answering the question. However, their answer no longer exists.

The ID is not the ID of the comment but rather the ID of the now-deleted answer. The page does not scroll anywhere because the answer has been deleted, and you do not have the privilege to see deleted posts, so the anchor to scroll to does not exist. Should you have the privilege, the link works fine and scrolls to the deleted answer.

Comment: NAA?? What does it means?

Comment: @SathiyaKumar Not An Answer

Comment: If a mod has been removed that answer means, that should be reflected in home page right? (Like `modified -- ago` by @modname)

Comment: @SathiyaKumar Deletions don't bump also.